# Perform action of SQL Trigger only if at least one column except a specific column has been changed

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

i got a table `Table1` defined as:

```
| ID | Foo | Bar | Foobar |
```

Another Table `Table2` has been defined as:

```
| Asdf | Qwertz |
```

I've now successfully created a trigger that updates an entry in another table, as soon as something in this table has been changed:

```
CREATE TRIGGER 
  MyFancyTrigger 
ON 
  [dbo].[Table1] 
AFTER UPDATE 
AS 
  UPDATE 
    [dbo].[Table2] 
  SET 
    Asdf = NEWID() 
  WHERE 
    Qwertz = 'SomeConstant'
```

This trigger works so far. I'd like to change the trigger in that way, that it only performs the update-query, if at least anything except of column `Foobar` has been changed. If a column has been changed along with column `Foobar` has been changed, it should update `Table2` aswell.

**Examples**:

- `UPDATE Table1 SET Foobar = NEWID()` should *not* change `Table2`.
- `UPDATE Table1 SET Foo = NEWID()` *should* change `Table2`.
- `UPDATE Table1 SET Foo = NEWID(), Foobar = NEWID()` *should* change `Table2`.

I tried to do it with `IF COLUMNS_UPDATED() > 1 OR NOT UPDATE(Foobar)` but that does not seem to work. Any hints?

I'm working on a SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: I'm wondering what happened when you 'tried to do it with IF COLUMNS_UPDATED() > 1 OR NOT UPDATE(Foobar)' ? That approach should work.

Comment: It just triggers the update as if the `IF` would be missing. Triggers 100% of the time, even for the first example.